# C# - 'The given path's format is not supported.'

Tags: c#

```
private void saveStudent<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite) 
{
  stream = File.OpenWrite(filePath); **//Error is here**
  var binaryData = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
  binaryData.Serialize(stream, objectToWrite);
  stream.Close();
}
```

Comment: i'm new here so not sure how all this works.

Comment: What is the value of `filePath` and what platform is this running on?

Comment: What is the value of `filePath`?

Comment: Windows 10 
string filePath = "DriveName:\\Folder\\FileName.Extension";@Ilian Pinzon

Comment: DriveName doesn't sound like a valid drive

Comment: I call shenanigans, please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite(v=vs.110).aspx and then https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: Please don't use `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there has been no attempt to debug this code and no attempt at reading the documentation. Additionally no attempt to put the relevant details in the question

Comment: well just coding using what my teacher gave to me i tried C:\\ it didnt work @KeithNicholas

Comment: if you don't show us the EXACT string you are using we can't help  it needs to be a valid  file path

Comment: it can't be C:\\  that's not a path to a file

Comment: private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stud = new Student();
            stud.setStudentID(studentIDTextBox.Text);
            stud.setFirstName(firstNameTextBox.Text);
            stud.setLastName(lastNameTextBox.Text);


                 saveStudent<Student>(filePath, stud);

            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        } @KeithNicholas sorry im i dont know how put it in that fancy coding box

Comment: @SpicySensei, you need to help us help you.
What is the absolute file path you're passing through?
Chances are it's just an OS specific slash problem that would be simple as sin to fix, but we just need the info.

Comment: @JamesWhyte what do mean by absolute file path ? like where file is located ?

Comment: best solution to this problem is get better understanding of concepts before asking a question sorry for inconvenience i wasted your time when you could have help others sorry everyone